# C#: System.ComponentModel.Design does not contain ArrayEditor

Tags: c#, designer, system.componentmodel

I'm working on making a complex object designer compliant and was going to utilize the ArrayEditor component... Needless to say, I don't have it... MSDN says it comes from .NET 1.1 which I most certainly do have and then some. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the System.ComponentModel.Design namespace of the System.Design dll.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Bit more googling resolved the matter.

http://www.csharpfriends.com/Forums/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=45253

Apparently, ArrayEditor resides in System.Design.dll, not System.dll which provides access to System.ComponentModel.Design. :/